# Can we extend the definition of a continuous function to binary relations?

Tags: general-topology, relations

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. A function $\phi:X\to Y$ is continuous iff for any open subset $A\subseteq Y,$ the preimage $\phi^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X.$ We could similarly define a relation $\rho\subseteq X\times Y$ to be continuous iff $\rho^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$ for any open subset $A\subseteq Y$. It can be easily seen that the composition of such relations again satisfies the condition and that the identity relation does. I had my first lecture in category theory  this week so I know this gives us a category with topological spaces as objects and relations as morphisms. This is a good thing, I imagine.

For example, let's take $\rho=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\,|\,x^2+y^2=1\}.$ Clearly, for any open interval $(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb R,$ we have $\rho^{-1}((a,b))$ open in $\mathbb R$, and since open intervals form a basis in $\mathbb R$, this is true for any open subset $A\subseteq \mathbb R.$ So a relation that "looks continuous" is continuous in the sense defined in the previous paragraph.

However, this is hardly evidence for the notion being useful. Therefore, I would like to ask whether it makes any sense to consider such relations and whether they have been considered. I have googled "continuous binary relations" but the hits seem to be irrelevant (but perhaps the terminology has been too cryptic for me to understand they're not).

**EDIT** I have asked an analogous question about homomorphisms [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148715/can-we-extend-the-definition-of-a-homomorphism-to-binary-relations).

Comment: I use the notion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95213/branch-point-what-makes-a-closed-loop-around-it-special/95352#95352) to define a rigorous notion of "continuous multivalued function". Of course, what I'm really doing is defining a weak covering space...

Comment: related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179123/continuous-relations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two notions of preimage for general relations used in topology. I use the notation $y\in\phi(x)$ for $(x,y)\in\phi$. Let $\phi$ be a relation between $X$ and $Y$, aka a subset of $X\times Y$. Let $B\subseteq Y$. The *upper inverse* $\phi^+(B)$ of $B$ is $$\phi^+(B)=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\subseteq B\}.$$
The *lower inverse* $\phi^-(B)$ of $B$ is $$\phi^-(B)=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\cap B\neq\emptyset\}.$$
If $X$ and $Y$ come endowed with a topology, then we say that $\phi$ is *upper hemicontinuous* if the upper inverse of every open set is open, *lower hemicontinuous* if the lower inverse of every open set is open, and *continuous* if it is both upper and lower hemicontinuous.

These notions are very, very useful. Examples where continuity of relations (usually known as *correspondences* in this context) matters are the [Maximum theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem) of Berge and the [Kakutani fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem). Both are fundamental tools in mathematical economics, where these notions play a big role. A great reference for these (and many other) concepts is [Infinite Dimensional Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540295860) by Aliprantis and Border.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain why we need the two notions?

Comment: In economics, agents are usually modeled as maximizing some goal function. If their constraints vary continuously as a correspondence and their goal function is continuous (and the other conditions of the Maximum theorem hold), the choice set will vary upper-hemicontinuously. Now solution concepts in economic modelling and game theory such as Walrasian equilibrium or Nash equilibrium can be seen as fixed points of a correspondence- and the Kakutani fixed point theorem allows one to show that such a fixed point exists.