# A concept of "continuous relations" in finite topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, relations

For $\mathcal R\subseteq X\times X^\prime$, $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq X^\prime$ define:

$A\mathcal R=\{y\in X^\prime\mid \exists a\in A:(a,y)\in \mathcal R\}$
$\mathcal R B=\{x\in X\mid \exists b\in B:(x,b)\in \mathcal R\}$

Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(X^\prime,\tau^\prime)$ be finite topological spaces. Suppose that $\mathcal R $ is such that
$$A^\prime\subseteq X^\prime\implies\overline{\mathcal R A^\prime}\mathcal R
\subseteq \overline{A^\prime}\tag{1}$$

Does the corresponding then holds for $\mathcal R^{op}$, defined by
$(y,x)\in\mathcal R^{op}\iff(x,y)\in\mathcal R$?

$$A\subseteq X\implies\overline{\mathcal R^{op} A}\mathcal R^{op}
\subseteq \overline{A}\tag{2}$$

The only context I have so far, is that $(1)$ is a consistent extension of the definition of continuous functions on finite topological spaces. See [A proof that continuity of $f:X\to Y$ is equivalent to $\overline{f^{-1}(M)}\subset f^{-1}(\overline{M})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907899/a-proof-that-continuity-of-fx-to-y-is-equivalent-to-overlinef-1m-sub)

Comment: What is $\mathcal{R}^{op}$?

Comment: See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179123/continuous-relations) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110501/can-we-extend-the-definition-of-a-continuous-function-to-binary-relations?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

While walking our dogs I found a counterexample:

Given a constant function $f:X\to Y$ such that $\{f(x)\}$ is closed. Then $f$ is continuous as a function and therefor as a relation. Given a proper closed subset $A\subset X$. Then $\overline{f^{op}A}f^{op}=X$ which isn't a subset of $A$.

My intuition was wrong.